# How to insert PHP in contact form 7 field body

Tags: php, contact-form-7

Do somebody can help me figure out , how to make my PHP code work in contact form 7 body fiel ??

Here is the PHP i want to put in it

`<?php echo $some_variable; ?>`

Notes: the variable $some_variable; already exist in my backend function.php file here

```
    $s$some_variable; = str_replace("\n", "<br>", get_option('some_variable;'));
  } else {
    $some_variable = "some text !";
  }
```

Thanks for your help

How my form looks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("form-group").reset();
</script>



  <label style="font-size:18px; color:#ffffff;"><?php echo $some_variable; ?></label> /// HERE IS WHEN I WANT TO PUT THE PHP CODE


<div id="optionstep2">
   <select class="options" name="selling">
                        <option value="--Selling In--">texxt</option>
                        <option value="1-3 Months">text 1</option>
                        <option value="3-6 Months">texte 2</option>
                      
                    </select>
  </div>


  </div>

<div>
[submit class:btn class:btn-danger id:sendform2 "send"]
</div>
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you want. You write "how to make my PHP code work". What do you mean? Work how?

Comment: Actually i am trying to put this php code into the body field but it's not working on the form front end, i need somebody for help me figure out this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people like me who gonna get this kind of issue,
i succeded fixing this just by putting some javascript into the contact form 7 body

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#putphp').val('<?php echo $some_variable; ?>');
});
</script>
```